# Layout issue with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Recently picking up android development, I have hit a snag in the road. I'm having trouble positioning my layouts. Screenshots are as follows:

[image: originalLayout]

I'm trying to input either another layout type/list view in the upper section of the screen, without disrupting the button/text box at the bottom, though.. When extending this layout. I hit the following snag:

[image: Modified Layout]

The entire contents of the original frame shift when the box of the new layout is extended, I've tried modifying:

```
android:layout_gravity="top">
```

and other layout attributes such as weight, margin, height/width.. This always hits the same problem.

My XML for this view is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="483dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.06"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        </FrameLayout>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="SendMessageButton"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Though, i'm some-what stuck on how to make the correct changes & any response to this question would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, all your child views live inside a single horizontally-oriented `LinearLayout`. `LinearLayout`s always arrange views sequentially, as you are experiencing.

There are a couple different ways to achieve the layout you are looking for. I'm going to suggest one that uses nested `LinearLayout`s (an outer one to stack things vertically, and then a nested one to arrange the `EditText` and `Button` horizontally), but you could also consider using a `RelativeLayout` for this.

Updated layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:onClick="SendMessageButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that a `LinearLayout` is oriented horizontally by default; I have explicitly included the attribute here to make the structure more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, your button and editText is appearing far from the frame layout and not near the corner is the parent layout orientation is Horizontal.

Change it to Vertical.

Now, if you need your button and editText to be arranged in the same line, it should be mentioned as described in samgak answer.

However, i would like to suggest the following.

1. Using framelayout might create bad user experience across different screen sizes in android.
2. If the parent layout in Linear, if the screen size is x and all your components added if the height it takes is x-20, then the theme you set for parent layout would not cover the entire screen. Therefore, it is recommended to use RelativeLayout and for the button and editText, use the layout_alignParentBottom = true attribute.

If needed, i can share the  code sample for this. Added Vertical Scroll to the layout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="483dp"

        android:layout_gravity="top">

        </FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="Edit Message"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="SendMessageButton"

        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: "Using framelayout might create bad user experience across different screen sizes in android." This is true if you use a fixed height as in the original xml; using a weight _only_ to specify the `FrameLayout` height avoids this issue entirely.